# Calling an object's method defined in List

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I'm trying to call addContact method from main method using *ArrayList* called phone but its not working.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class A {

    String name;
    int num;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public A(String name, int num) {
        this.name= name;
        this.num= num;
    }

    public void addContact() {
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number:");
        num = sc.nextInt();
    }
}

public class Main {
    static void menu() {
        System.out.println("1. add");
        System.out.println("2. break");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList <A> phone;

        while(true) {
            menu();
            int c = sc.nextInt();
            if(c==1) {
                phone.add().addContact();
                //I'm trying to call addContact()
            } else if(c==2) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why I can't just call `phone.add().addContact()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class A {
String name;
int num;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public A(String name, int num) {
    this.name= name;
    this.num= num;
}

}

public class Main {
static void menu()  
{
    System.out.println("1. add");
    System.out.println("2. break");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList <A> phone = new Arraylist<A>();

    while(true)
    {
        menu();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        if(c==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name:");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter number:");
            int num = sc.nextInt(); 
            phone.add(new A(name,num));

        }
        else if(c==2)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Just removed you addContact and placed in in the while. Now i create a new Instance of A and add it to the list. This should work now. Please post more precise Questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of your list:

ArrayList<A> phone = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: where to add these lines?

Comment: in your main method

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts here:

```
 ArrayList <A> phone;
```

only declares that list; but doesnt define it. Thus you run into a **NullPointerException** when you try to run your code.

You need

```
 ArrayList <A> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead. I took the freedom to give that variable a **reasonable** name, too. (this list is about storing contents, it is not storing phones; and it is also not a single phone ... just a list of contact information)

But there is more. You see, you are getting your abstractions wrong. Your *Contact* class (A is just a **terrible** name for that class) should **not** be dealing with a scanner to fetch its data.

Instead, you want to do something like:

```
class Contact {
   private final String name;
   private final int number;

   Contact(String name, int number) {
     this.name = name;
     this.number = number;
   }
```

and then, **within** your main method, you do something like:

```
 boolean loop = true;

 while (loop) {
  ... have user enter a name and a number
  if (name.equals("STOP")) {
    loop = false;
  } else {
    Contact contact = new Contact(name, number);
    phones.add(contact);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ArrayList <A> phone;
```

Should be:
    ArrayList  phone = new ArrayList();

Also, the add() method in this line

```
phone.add().addContact();
```

should contain an A object to add to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return object of A

```
 public A  addContact() {
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter name:");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter number:");
            num = sc.nextInt();
    return new A(name,num);
        }
```

and

```
 if(c==1)
            {
                phone.add(addContact);                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't give the working code. Just check below points to make your program better.

1. Why you are creating constructor with arguments when you using add contact method.
2. Where you are created object for `class A` in `class Main`.
3. Try to check how to use `ArrayList class`. Because you are not using **add()** properly.